# How to connect JPL with SWI-Prolog in Mac OS X

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, prolog, swi-prolog

Hi i have a problem with a jpl interface. I want connect JPL with swi-prolog installed with mac-ports with eclipse. I have a jpl.jar and i have tried to import the jar file in eclipse with build path but i have this error: "no jpl in java.library.path".
So i have copied libjpl.dylib in a /opt/local/lib/swipl-7.1.29/bin/ and when i execute the code i have this error: "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /opt/local/lib/swipl-7.1.29/bin/libjpl.dylib: dlopen(/opt/local/lib/swipl-7.1.29/bin/libjpl.dylib, 1): Library not loaded: /Users/janw/stable/lib/swipl/lib/x86_64-darwin13.0.0/libswipl.dylib
  Referenced from: /opt/local/lib/swipl-7.1.29/bin/libjpl.dylib
  Reason: image not found"

Answer (score 4):

After a anoying waste of time i found the solution about that problem.
First of all, its completely necesary to install swi-prolog via macports, if not, as i did, when you point in the

`Djava.library.path=/users/rivax/Applications/SWI-Prolog.app/Contents/swipl/lib/x86_64-darwin13.0.0`

this exception will apear

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /Users/rivax/Applications/SWI-Prolog.app/Contents/swipl/lib/x86_64-darwin13.0.0/libjpl.dylib: dlopen(/Users/rivax/Applications/SWI-Prolog.app/Contents/swipl/lib/x86_64-darwin13.0.0/libjpl.dylib, 1): Library not loaded: /Users/janw/stable/lib/swipl/lib/x86_64-darwin13.0.0/libswipl.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/rivax/Applications/SWI-Prolog.app/Contents/swipl/lib/x86_64-darwin13.0.0/libjpl.dylib
  Reason: image not found
    at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary1(ClassLoader.java:1965)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1890)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1880)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:849)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1088)
    at jpl.JPL.loadNativeLibrary(JPL.java:100)
    at jpl.fli.Prolog.<clinit>(Prolog.java:85)
    at jpl.Query.open(Query.java:286)
    at jpl.Util.textToTerm(Util.java:162)
    at jpl.Query.<init>(Query.java:198)
    at consultasProlog.Consultas.consultaFicheroProlog(Consultas.java:19)
    at utilidades.RellenarModelo.ejecutarArchivo(RellenarModelo.java:30)
    at javaprolog.JavaProlog.main(JavaProlog.java:30)
Java Result: 1`

So follow these steps.

1. port install swi-prolog on terminal , if you dont have install already macports command not found will apear so go to https://www.macports.org/install.php and install macports.
2. navigate to the path of swi prolog macports installation which mine is
   `/opt/local/lib/swipl-6.6.6/lib/x86_64-darwin14.0.0`
3. copy this path and set in java.library.path in the java VM as  `-Djava.library.path=/opt/local/lib/swipl-6.6.6/lib/x86_64-darwin14.0.0`

Now .pl with jpl.jar will be able to execute and the consults will run.

Hope it will help you and every person who find this hell problem.

Cheers frank.

Comment: I'm having the same problem, but I dont understand why does it not work when it's not install via macport or homebrew ? Because the path is still absolute

Comment: I tried that approach as an alternative to [this one](https://ssardina-research.github.io/packages-jpl/DeploymentMacos). I am still getting 'no jpl in java.library.path'.

Comment: Nevermind. It worked. I just had put the VM argument in the program argument field... But I don't think using Macports mattered in the end.